# Test private field with RSpec

Tags: ruby, rspec

Let's say I have such a class:

```
class A
  def initialize(arg)
    @arg = arg
  end
end

a = A.new(123)
```

Is it possible to test the value of `@arg` with RSpec without changing this code?

Comment: While it is possible, you should not do this as you will be coupling your test to the implementation of the class. Unit tests are to test the behaviour of the class, if you are not exposing `@arg` with an accessor, it is not part of you public interface and testing it will make your test extremely brittle in a face of any refactor, for example renaming it to `@argument` will break your test without change in behaviour.

Comment:  This. But alas, rules are made to be broken. You **MIGHT (!!!)** have a legitimate use case where the best pragmatic option is to test an internal instance variable, and the answer below shows how to do it. But please ask yourself, is this really the best available option? If `@arg` is actually meant to be accessible from  outside the object, why not add `attr_reader :arg`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. Use `instance_variable_get` method:

```
irb(main):014:0> a = A.new(123)
irb(main):015:0> a.instance_variable_get(:@arg)
=> 123
```

https://apidock.com/ruby/v2_5_5/Object/instance_variable_get